# How can I generate datagrid columns from XML elements?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, wpfdatagrid

The columns below are simply those present in the XML.  How can I get them generated automatically?  Or perhaps DataGrid doesn't support that operation and I can only get there by converting to DataSet?

```
<DataGrid 
        DataContext="{Binding XPath=mold_details/plate_list}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=row}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Name="dataGrid2" 
        Margin="20,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="name" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Length" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=length}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Width" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=width}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Setting AutoGenerateColumns="true" does NOT yield a table showing XML elements.  It yields a table showing XmlDataProvider properties.

Comment: -1 Try *looking at your code* before asking questions here... what do you think `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` does?

Comment: You're looking for `AutoGenerateColumns`.

Comment: I know AutoGenerateColumns, but it generates based on Path, which is wrong.  We need to use XPath to get stuff.

Comment: Do I understand well that code above works but you would like to use [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)? If yes then unfortunately _"DataGrid cannot auto-generate columns when the source is XML data."_

Comment: You understand right, dkozl.  I guess my next step is to write my own code to generate columns from XML source data.

Comment: DataGrid cannot auto-generate columns when the source is XML data. In this case, create a custom Columns collection. For an example, see DataGridTextColumn... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx

Comment: +1 My mistake... down vote removed.